# php Sessions are not being destroyed even after logout in IE 8 and 9

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, logout

I am trying to find out what is wrong with this code below, whenever I tried to logout using Internet Explorer, I could not able to do that, It only logs out after several reloads or after closing the browser.

```
 <?php
//Start session 
session_start();
require("../../class-settings.php");
function write_at_sess_destroy(){
    $time=date('h:i:s A',time());
    $sql="update " . DB_PRE."user_master set `guid` = '',`user_first_login`='0' WHERE user_id ='".  $_SESSION['user']."'";
    $sql_log= "update " . DB_PRE."user_log set logout_time='$time' where user_id='{$_SESSION['user']}' and logger_id='{$_SESSION['DYNAMIC_LOGGER_ID']}'";       
    if(mysql_query($sql))if(mysql_query($sql_log)) return true;
}
if(write_at_sess_destroy()){
    function unset_sessions(){
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['adminlang'])unset($_SESSION['adminlang']);
        unset($_SESSION['loginID']);
        unset($_SESSION['utype']);
        return true;
    }
    if(session_destroy()){
        header("Location:../../../");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        echo "error...";    
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: From where do you call `unset_sessions`? And why does this function have a `session_start`?

Comment: Don't know if that is the fault, but header HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: and not a relative location ../../../ see: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: You could set the session value to false on logout, and then determine the login status based on whether the value is false or otherwise?

Comment: @donald123

I tried that one too, but result is the same...

Comment: Sorry @Daniel I forgot to mention that, I put that above if(session_destroy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you simplify:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("../../class-settings.php");
    function write_at_sess_destroy(){
        $time=date('h:i:s A',time());
        $sql = "update " . DB_PRE."user_master set `guid` = '',`user_first_login`='0' WHERE user_id ='".  $_SESSION['user']."'";
        $sql_log = "update " . DB_PRE."user_log set logout_time='$time' where user_id='{$_SESSION['user']}' and logger_id='{$_SESSION['DYNAMIC_LOGGER_ID']}'";       
        if(mysql_query($sql))if(mysql_query($sql_log)) return true;
    }
    if(write_at_sess_destroy()){
        session_regenerate_id();
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION = array();
        header("Location: ../../../");
        exit;
    } else {
        echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: @SleepingDragon: Why did you accept the answer if your problem apparently wasn't solved with it?